# Disallow access to Sonatype Nexus & Webmin?

Tags: linux, webserver, nginx

I have a VPS running my family's business website and my personal development site. I have Sonatype Nexus, Jenkins, Webmin etc installed *for me*. They'll never use it for the business. I don't want a customer accidentally visiting businessdomain.com:8001/nexus or businessdomain.com:10000 etc...I would also prefer robots didn't know about these for the business site either (nor mine, but that's fine if they do, as it's mine)

Thanks for any information you can give me.

Edit: Even better, how could I get Sonatype Nexus to only serve to **nexus.personaldomain.com** and webmin to **webmin.personaldomain.com**? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having these ports directly exposed to the internet under any domain is a bad idea.  I would block outside access to those ports.

Then install a VPN.

Then when you want to get in connect to the VPN and get internal access to the network.

The VPN will have an internal to them IP and you can use your web browser normally.

Comment: Hmmm...thanks. Can you explain how I can do this, or link me to a tutorial? This might also be useful to later readers.

Comment: Here is the windows way do you need a linux example? http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

Comment: A linux example would be what I need. Sorry for the inconvenience! And thanks for your research :)

Comment: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install    The link will jump you to the middle of the page, once installed scroll up and down and review the rest of this webpage.  Try that out and let me know.

Comment: Wait, actually, I'm not sure this will work as my IDE will need to be able to connect to the ports.

Comment: It will still work.  Your PC will have 2 ip addresses one them being virtual.  After you establish a connection with, for example, business.com, the VPN server will give you an internal IP address,for example 192.168.4.100.  The server could be on 192.168.4.3, for example.  Then you open your program and point it to 192.168.4.3 and it will have full access to all ports unless otherwise blocked by security measures.